# the highest common factor of $n-11$ and $3n+20$ is greater than 1?

Tags: number-theory

what is the smallest positive integer $n$,where $n\neq 11$,such that the highest common factor of $n-11$ and $3n+20$ is greater than 1?

This problem is Singapore Mathematical Olympiad (SMO)2013 Junior Section (First Round)

Answer (score 4):

First note that $\gcd(n-11,3n+20) = \gcd(n-11,53)$. Since $53$ is prime, $\gcd(n-11,53)\in\{1,53\}$ hence we are looking for $n$ such that $n-11$ is a non-zero multiple of $53$. The smallest such $n$ is $64$.

Answer (score 2):

We will use $(a,b) = (a, a-b)$ where $(a,b)$ denotes the h.c.f of $a$ and $b$.

$(n-11, 3n+20) = (n-11, 2n+31) = (n-11, n + 42) = (n-11, 53) = d$

If $d > 1$, then $d = 53$ since $53$ is prime. Therefore $53$ must divide $n-11$ and the smallest such $n$ is $64$.

Answer (score 0):

HINT:

If $d$ divides  $n-11,3n+20,$ it will divide $3n+20-3(n-11)=53$

So we need $n-11=53\implies n=64$ and $3n+20=3(n-11)+53$ is clearly divisible by $53$